# My maze does not block character movement once it gets past the first tile

Tags: java, loops, graphics, graphics2d, maze

I currently have a maze project that is built of four tiles that form a loop when moving around to create an endless universe. Initially when inputting character blocking abilities, my second maze tile (the tile directly to the left of the character starting tile) displayed the blocking program one block off. The further you would move to the left onto the initial tile and back to the second tile, the more the character would be blocked off from the original tile. I assumed the problem lied within the tile placement, as the character would switch tiles, they would be one off. I altered my tile coordinates and size which somehow created a new problem. Now, the initial starting tile blocks appropriately, but once the character enters another tile, the blocking no longer works at all and the character is able to just proceed in an infinite loop around the maze. Attached is two classes: InTheDark (the class that calls the AppWindow) and AppWindow (the class consisting of the methods that develop the maze and the flashlight capabilities - they were commented out for the purpose of better access to the game). Some segments of code are commented out for the reason that they are functioning, but have no affect on the background. Could someone please help me on figuring out where the error is coming from?

This code contains InTheDark and AppWindow.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.applet.*;
import java.util.Random;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;

public class InTheDark
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {    //launches the frame and timer events
      int winWid = 500;
      int winHei = 500;
      AppWindow runner = new AppWindow(winWid,winHei);
      runner.addWindowListener(
         new WindowAdapter()
         {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {System.exit(0);}});
      runner.setSize(winWid,winHei);
      runner.show();
   }

}


class AppWindow extends Frame implements KeyListener
{
   int wid=0; //size of display window  wid 
   int hei=0; //size of display window height

   Image virtualMem;
   Graphics gBuffer;
   Image mazeBackgroundCenter;
   Image mazeBackgroundElse;
   Image character;

   Graphics2D g2D;

   int cx, cy;

   int bx1, by1;

   int bx2, by2;

   int bx3, by3;

   int bx4, by4;

   int[][] maze11 = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1},
                    {1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1},
                    {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1},
                    {1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1},
                    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};
   int[][] maze22 = {{1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1},
                    {1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1},
                    {1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1},
                    {1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
                    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1},
                    {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1},
                    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1}};
   int[][] maze33 = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                    {0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0},
                    {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1},
                    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};
   int[][] maze44 = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1},
                    {1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1},
                    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1},
                    {1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1},
                    {0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1},
                    {1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}};

   int[] charpos;

   String line = null;

   int batterywidth;

   boolean flashlight;

   boolean left,right,up,down;

   public AppWindow(int width, int height)
   {
      virtualMem = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      gBuffer = virtualMem.getGraphics();
      wid = width;
      hei = height;

      batterywidth = 40;

      g2D = (Graphics2D)gBuffer;

      flashlight = false;

      charpos = new int[3];

      charpos[0] = 1;
      charpos[1] = 4;
      charpos[2] = 4;

      cx = 225;
      cy = 225;

      bx1 = 0;
      by1 = 0;

      bx2 = -500;
      by2 = 0;

      bx3 = 0;
      by3 = -500;

      bx4 = -500;
      by4 = -500;

      left = true;
      right = true;
      up = true;
      down = true;

      addKeyListener(this);
   }

   public void update(Graphics g)
   {
      paint(g);
   }

   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      updateBackground();
      placeCharacter();

      if(charpos[0] == 1)
      {
         canMoveLeft(maze11);
         canMoveRight(maze11);
         canMoveUp(maze11);
         canMoveDown(maze11);
      }

      if(charpos[0] == 2)
      {
         canMoveLeft(maze22);
         canMoveRight(maze22);
         canMoveUp(maze22);
         canMoveDown(maze22);
      }

      if(charpos[0] == 3)
      {
         canMoveLeft(maze33);
         canMoveRight(maze33);
         canMoveUp(maze33);
         canMoveDown(maze33);
      }

      if(charpos[0] == 4)
      {
         canMoveLeft(maze44);
         canMoveRight(maze44);
         canMoveUp(maze44);
         canMoveDown(maze44);
      }   

      /*if(batterywidth >= 1)
      {
         theLights();
         if(batterywidth == 15)
         {
            gBuffer.setColor(Color.white);
            gBuffer.drawString("Looks like you are getting close to running out of batteries.",50,470);
            gBuffer.drawString("Look around and see if you can find any around the maze.",50,480);
         }
         battery();
      }
      if(batterywidth < 1)
      {
         flashlight = false;
         theLights();
         gBuffer.setColor(Color.white);
         gBuffer.drawString("You are out of batteries. Try finding some around the maze.",50,470);
         gBuffer.drawString("They will be the only things you can see in the dark.",50,480);

         battery();
      }

      extraBatteries();*/

      g.drawImage(virtualMem, 0, 0, this);

      repaint();
   }

   public void extraBatteries()
   {
   }

   public void theLights()
   {
      /*Color blck = new Color(0,0,0,240);
      Rectangle2D.Double darkness = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,500,500);
      Area glow = new Area(darkness);
      if(flashlight)
      {
         Ellipse2D.Double light = new Ellipse2D.Double(cx-100,cy-100, 200, 200);

         Area shiny = new Area(light);
         glow.subtract(shiny);

         Color yllw = new Color(189,183,107,200);
         g2D.setPaint(yllw);
         g2D.fill(shiny);

      }
      g2D.setPaint(blck);
      g2D.fill(glow);*/
   }

   public void battery()
   {
      if(flashlight)
      {
         long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
         if(time % 500 == 0)
         {
            batterywidth --;
         }
      }

      Color drkgrn = new Color(0,128,0,200);
      Color lghtgrn = new Color(154,205,50,200);
      Color yellow = new Color(255,215,0,200);
      Color red = new Color(255,0,0,200);

      if(batterywidth <= 40)
      {
         g2D.setPaint(drkgrn);
         if(batterywidth <= 30)
         {
            g2D.setPaint(lghtgrn);
            if(batterywidth <= 20)
            {
               g2D.setPaint(yellow);
               if(batterywidth <= 10)
               {
                  g2D.setPaint(red);
               }
            }
         }
      }

      Rectangle2D.Double grn = new Rectangle2D.Double(420,440,batterywidth,20);
      Area battery = new Area(grn);

      g2D.fill(battery);
   }

   public void canMoveLeft(int[][] maze00)
   {
      if(charpos[2]-1 > -1 && charpos[1] > 0 && charpos[1] < 11 && charpos[2] < 11)
      {
         if(maze00[charpos[1]][charpos[2]-1] == 0)
         {
            left = true;
         }
         else
         {
            left = false;
         }
      } 
      else
      {
         if(charpos[2]-1 < 0)
         {
            charpos[2] = 11;
            if(charpos[0] == 1)
            {
               charpos[0] = 2;

            }
            else
            {
               charpos[0] = 1;
            }
         }
         if(charpos[2] >= 10)
         {
            charpos[2] = 1;
            if(charpos[0] == 1)
            {
               charpos[0] = 2;
            }
            else
            {
               charpos[0] = 1;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public void canMoveRight(int[][] maze00)
   {
      if(charpos[2]+1 < 12 && charpos[1] > 0 && charpos[1] < 11 && charpos[2] > 0)
      {

         if(maze00[charpos[1]][charpos[2]+1] == 0)
         {
            right = true;
         }
         else
         {
            right = false;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         if(charpos[2]-1 < 0)
         {
            charpos[2] = 11;
            if(charpos[0] == 1)
            {
               charpos[0] = 2;

            }
            else
            {
               charpos[0] = 1;
            }
         }
         if(charpos[2] >= 10)
         {
            charpos[2] = 1;
            if(charpos[0] == 1)
            {
               charpos[0] = 2;
            }
            else
            {
               charpos[0] = 1;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public void canMoveUp(int[][] maze00)
   {
      if(charpos[1]-1 > -1 && charpos[2] > 0 && charpos[2] < 11 && charpos[1] < 11)
      {

         if(maze00[charpos[1]-1][charpos[2]] == 0)
         {
            up = true;
         }
         else
         {
            up = false;
         } 
      }
      else
      {
         if(charpos[1]-1 < 0)
         {
            charpos[1] = 11;
            if(charpos[0] == 1)
            {
               charpos[0] = 3;

            }
            else
            {
               charpos[0] = 1;
            }
         }
         if(charpos[1] >= 10)
         {
            charpos[1] = 1;
            if(charpos[0] == 1)
            {
               charpos[0] = 3;
            }
            else
            {
               charpos[0] = 1;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public void canMoveDown(int[][] maze00)
   {
      if(charpos[1]+1 < 12 && charpos[2] > 0 && charpos[2] < 11 && charpos[1] > 0)
      {

         if(maze00[charpos[1]+1][charpos[2]] == 0)
         {
            down = true;
         }
         else
         {
            down = false;
         }
      }
      else
      {
         if(charpos[1]-1 < 0)
         {
            charpos[1] = 11;
            if(charpos[0] == 1)
            {
               charpos[0] = 3;

            }
            else
            {
               charpos[0] = 1;
            }
         }
         if(charpos[1] >= 10)
         {
            charpos[1] = 1;
            if(charpos[0] == 1)
            {
               charpos[0] = 3;
            }
            else
            {
               charpos[0] = 1;
            }
         }
      } 
   }

   public void updateBackground()
   {
      if(bx1 > 500)
      {
         bx1 = -500;
         bx3 = -500;
      }
      if(bx2 > 500)
      {
         bx2 = -500;
         bx4 = -500;
      }
      if(bx1 < -500)
      {
         bx1 = 500;
         bx3 = 500;
      }
      if(bx2 < -500)
      {
         bx2 = 500;
         bx4 = 500;
      }
      if(by1 > 500)
      {
         by1 = -500;
         by2 = -500;
      }
      if(by3 > 500)
      {
         by3 = -500;
         by4 = -500;
      }
      if(by1 < -500)
      {
         by1 = 500;
         by2 = 500;
      }
      if(by3 < -500)
      {
         by3 = 500;
         by4 = 500;
      }

      drawFile(bx1,by1,maze11);
      drawFile(bx2,by2,maze22);
      drawFile(bx3,by3,maze33);
      drawFile(bx4,by4,maze44);  
   }

   public void drawFile(int x, int y, int[][] maze00)
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < maze00.length; i ++)
      {
         for(int ii = 0; ii < maze00[i].length; ii++)
         {
            if(maze00[i][ii] == 1)
            {
               gBuffer.setColor(Grfx.black);
            }
            if(maze00[i][ii] == 0)
            {
               gBuffer.setColor(Grfx.white);
            }
            gBuffer.fillRect(x + ii*50, y + i*50, 50, 50);
         }
      }
   }

   public void placeCharacter()
   {
      gBuffer.setColor(Grfx.red);
      gBuffer.fillOval(cx-10,cy-10,20,20);

   }

   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)     { }

   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)        { }

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
   {
      int key = e.getKeyCode();

      if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
      {
         int buff1 = bx1;
         if(left)
         {
            bx1+=50;
            bx2+=50;
            bx3+=50;
            bx4+=50;

            charpos[2]--;
         }
      }

      if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
      {
         int buff1 = bx1;
         if(right)
         {
            bx1-=50;
            bx2-=50;
            bx3-=50;
            bx4-=50;

            charpos[2]++;
         }
      }

      if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
      {
         if(down)
         {
            by1-=50;
            by2-=50;
            by3-=50;
            by4-=50;

            charpos[1] ++;

         }
      }

      if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
      {
         if(up)
         {
            by1+=50;
            by2+=50;
            by3+=50;
            by4+=50;


            charpos[1] --;

         }
      }
      if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
      {
         if(flashlight)
         {
            flashlight = false;
         }
         else
         {
            flashlight = true;
         }  
      }

      if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
      {
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: what is charpos[0] is for?

Comment: charpos[0] decides which tile the character is on.

Comment: what about charpos[1] & charpos[2] then? By the look of the code, you ++ or -- only chrapos[1] and charpos[2] when you move left/right/up/down.

Comment: charpos[1] and charpos[2] alter rows and columns. The canMoveLeft and Right and Up and Down change charpos[0] based on how far the character moves in the columns and rows.

Comment: you have a lot of mess in the code. It's barely readable. For example: `canMoveDown` method, instead of just checking if it can moveDown, does some other stuff, which looks pretty unrelated.
You also have code duplicates, which is a very bad practice. Instead you can break it to new methods.

Comment: The method canMoveDown also allows it to switch tiles as with all of the other canMoves. I am aware that there are some repeats, but those repeats are necessary depending on the direction the character is moving. The code runs fine for one maze tile, so there is clearly no fault in my repetition. Could you pinpoint where there is unrelated code in my methods?

Comment: Does the game consists of all 4 mazes combined?, When you go all the way left, which maze do you encounter?

Comment: OK, so instead of 1 full maze, you separate them into 4 small ones and then combine them back together, that's why you have pos[0]. Why not just have a single big maze? It would be much easier to check for legal moves.

Comment: The goal of the project is to have a scrolling background with looping tiles.

Comment: So how do you know if you get from maze11 to maze22, maze33, etc...?
The problem it seems, that while graphic does switch, your position doesn't.